# Substituting the contrapositive in one portion of logical expression?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, solution-verification

In first-order logic, is one allowed to substitute the contrapositive of an implication in only a portion of the expression? In particular, is the following logic correct:

$$[P \implies (Q \implies R)] \iff  [P \implies (\lnot R \implies \lnot Q)]$$

---

The number-theory portion, in plain language, is this:

**Proposition**: Given two coprime positive integers $a$ and $b$, their sum $c = a + b$ is coprime to both $a$ and $b$.

*Proof* (Using the contrapositive): We wish to show:

$$\color{blue}{ [a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}^+, a+b=c]} \implies \color{red}{[(a,b) = 1 \implies (a,c) = 1 \land (b,c) = 1]}
$$

The contrapositive of $\color{red}{[(a,b) = 1 \implies (a,c) = 1 \land (b,c) = 1]}$ is
$$\color{lime}{[(a,c) \neq 1 \lor (b,c) \neq 1 \implies (a,b) \neq 1]}$$

WLOG, assume that $a$ and $c$ are not coprime. Then there is some positive integer $d$ for which $(a,c) = d$, and we can write $a = a'd$ and $c = c'd$.

Now consider that:

$$a+b=c \implies a'd + b = c' d \implies a'd-c'd=b \implies b = d(c' - a')$$

But this means $d \mid b$, implying that $(a,b) \geq d \neq 1$. (We attain the same if $(b,c) \neq 1$.)

Having shown that for positive integers, $a+b=c$ implies the contrapositive, we infer the original statement is correct. QED.

---

Does this substitution and proof work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a statement and its contrapositive are interchangeable. If you want to be formal about it, you can prove it something like this:

$$\begin{array}{lcl} [P \implies (Q \implies R)], P & \vdash & P \land [P \implies (Q \implies R)]\\
[P \implies (Q \implies R)], P & \vdash & Q \implies R\\
[P \implies (Q \implies R)], P, \lnot R & \vdash & (Q \implies R) \land (\lnot R)\\
[P \implies (Q \implies R)], P, \lnot R & \vdash & \lnot Q \\
[P \implies (Q \implies R)], P & \vdash & \lnot R \implies \lnot Q \\
[P \implies (Q \implies R)] & \vdash & [P \implies (\lnot R \implies \lnot Q)]
\end{array}$$

where the steps are broadly reversible so that you can use them interchangeably.

Comment: That's a really interesting way of breaking the whole thing down formally!